# Refill one column in one file based on values from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files:

file1.csv:

```
fruit_count|fruit_id
10|1234-5
20|1560-0
40|4500-0
100|6700-0 
120|6770-8
110|5555-1 
80|6666-9
15|7777-4
13|3333-2
```

file2.csv:

```
fruit_id|fruit_name|n1|n2|
1234-5|strawbery||sweet|
4500-0|apple||sweet|
1560-0|orange||sweet|
6770-8|grape||sweet|
6666-9|peach||sweet|
7777-4|kiwi||sweet|
3333-6|blueberry||sweet|
9999-2|banana||sweet|
6666-3|grapefruit||sweet|
```

Desired output:

file3.csv

```
fruit_id|fruit_name|n1|n2|
1234-5|strawbery|10|sweet|
4500-0|apple|40|sweet|
1560-0|orange|20|sweet|
6770-8|grape|120|sweet|
6666-9|peach|80|sweet|
7777-4|kiwi|15|sweet|
3333-6|blueberry||sweet|
9999-2|banana||sweet|
6666-3|grapefruit||sweet|
```

So I want to import the column n1 in the file2.csv with the values from column fruit_count from the file1.csv if the fruit_id in both files are there and match. If there is no matching value, then the field in file3.csv should stay empty.

What I've tried:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{r[$2]=$1;next} {$3=r[$1]} 1' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

and:

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} 
           {
            if (NR==FNR) {
                r[$2]=$1; 
                next
            } 
            if ($1 in r){
                $3=r[$1]
            }
             print
           }' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you've tried? Your second command seems like it should work.

Comment: I get the file3.csv, but the column n1 is empty

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).